# How to translate ебовее?

Tags: одним-словом, прилагательные

It doesn't appear in a dictionary, however it seems to be a used word (like a vulgar version of cooler/better/funnier is what I can guess from the context?)

> А звучит **ебовее** чем Б

It also might be derived from *ебать* but it's hard to guess the actual meaning.

---

I asked this guy who wrote something like in the example, and he told me it was **мат**.

Comment: please provide some context. Where you heard/encountered this?

Comment: I'm Russian and hear this word for the first time. The most common **мат** word used to mean "good" is пиздатый (comparative: пиздатее) and "very good" is охуенный (comparative is охуеннее, but this form is not often used).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, it's a rude word for "cooler", "better". `ебовее` is a comparative form of the adjective `ебовый` that, in turn, is derived from the verb `ебать`.

Comment: Never heard both of them. Which region they are used in?

Comment: Thanks. I just want to ask if it can be taken always as positive? Or is just like "extrem" (either bad or good)?

Comment: @c.p. words of this kind don't always have a precise meaning. It's a verbalized emotion, like in English "that's a fuck of a movie!", which could only be interpreted in context.

Comment: @UVV, actually, I don't know where they are used. I think I heard it long time ago. Neither me, nor people who I know don't use it.

Comment: @Ivan if you don't mind me correcting your English it should be "Neither me nor people I know use it"

Comment: @UVV I would say this is universally understood

Comment: I bet that any native Russian could understand what this word means although he might never heared it before :)